# To donate something you want to throw away

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose that a person buys a packet of sugar. On the way home, the packet falls off his hands and the sugar scatters on the ground. Nobody is expected to gather the sugar again, but that person does so; of course not for his own use anymore, but to donate it to the poor!
Obviously, if the packet hadn't fallen down, he wouldn't have decided to donate it. It goes without saying that this kind of donation and charity is morally worthless and not considered a good deed.
Is there any English idiom to describe this kind of charity or donation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hopefully this sort of patronizing/demeaning behaviour doesn't happen often enough that people have a special term for it. But on the receiving end it's common enough to reject any such "offerings" with *I don't want your leftovers!* (or *leavings*).

Comment: One of the most heart-wrenching things I have witnessed in my life was near the end of the war when a delivery truck lost a case of eggs off the tailgate in the street, and the street-kids gathered round to scoop up the gooey mess and lick it off their fingers. It was probably the most nutritious thing they had to eat that week.

Comment: To FumbleFinge: 
This kind of behavior is so rare, but I just tried to give a concrete example of the situation I had in mind. The idiom can be generalized to other situations too.Example: you're having a date in a few minutes and you're getting ready to go out. Now, your little brother asks you to help him with his math and you refuse undoubtedly. But then, your girlfriend calls and cancels the date. Now, you put on a good-brother-mask and offer your brother your kind help. In fact, you are donating the time that you wouldn't have donated if your girlfriend hadn't cancelled the date.

Comment: It's like ["Ah, fuck it"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qj7shJtutA)

Comment: @Persique A "change of mind", or "having second thoughts" etc. should work. Right?

Comment: The context in your comment and that in your question don't seem to match.

Comment: Your second example is quite possibly morally justifiable, and the offer of help when the opportunity arises still laudable, whereas your first involves giving a gift that may in fact be injurious. These are very different scenarios.

Comment: It seems that there isn't any idiom referring to the situations described above.

Comment: @Edwin and Rathony, you're right. They're not exactly the same.

Comment: Undesirable materials being exported to foreign markets. This reminds me of the stories of Industrial by-products and normally rejected toxic things being put in foods for export by some Chinese food processors. I'm thinking of Melanin in baby formula because it was "light coloured like cream" and BHP stuff in canned and bottled foods.

Comment: @Stan fluoride as a byproduct of Uranium mining dumped in water supplies... Radioactive tailings mixed in to concrete used for making houses...

Comment: "hand-me-down" sugar? gross.

Comment: I don't think it quite fits the charity situation you describe (so just a comment), but ["regift"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regift) typically has similar connotations of giving away something you don't want yourself.

Comment: "fall off" his hands] is really "falls out of" his hands. The hands are like an enclosed  space (fall out of the cabinet or fall out of the tree), not a flat surface (fall off the table).

Comment: I found a great anecdote in a now deleted ""answer"...now visible to me as a 10K user. "

30+ years ago, author Russel Baker wrote a piece for the New York Times. Man looks in his pantry and finds nearly a dozen cans of tuna fish whose expiration date has passed. He suggests to his wife that he will drop them off at the food pantry. It would be a shame to throw the tuna away. She responds that it would be even worse to give expired tunafish to the poor. He thinks for a moment, agrees, and throws it away. ...[cont]

Comment: [cont] His wife tells him that he now has a moral obligation to buy 12 cans of tuna at the supermarket and on the way back home drop it off at the food pantry. --from [Joe Taxpayer](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5784/joetaxpayer)

Comment: @FumbleFingers But in the receiving end, there is **Don't look a gift horse in the mouth.**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***castoffs***

The type of charity described in the original question occurs on a country-wide scale sometimes. Recently, an EU member donated a large shipment of medicines to our local General Hospital; however, when it came time to distribute them, it was realized they were already expired.

There is a word to describe this type of donation of unwanted materials: they are ***cast-offs***.

> things, usually clothes, that you no longer want:

-[Cambridge Dictionary online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cast-offs)

**[Cast-offs](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cast-offs)** usually refers to old clothes which are given to poor relations or dumped in those large bins outside churches in the US, but the word could also be used to describe any unwanted item that is given away. A synonym is ***reject***.

Cast-offs are not usually rejected for being out-of-date in the third world: here old clothes are sold in *Mega-pacas* and clothe the majority of the poor people.

By way of contrast, I heard that [some US food chains are donating what they used to call “waste”:](https://earth911.com/food/darden-restaurants-harvest-program/)

> ...food that passes the restaurant-issued freshness date but is still entirely wholesome and edible by FDA standards is packaged, labeled and sent off to community organizations that feed the hungry, such as after-school programs, day cares, transition homes and rehabilitation centers.

[Some seek to go even further](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/01/08/bill-would-let-restaurant_n_1192494.html), donating left-overs and table gleanings.

“Demeaning” depends on your point of view. The morality of charity is not always clearly marked, and *hunger* may have its own sharply divided politics, but the unkindest cut of all is keenly felt as the  constant  [daily pang of hunger  in the bellies of at least 1/3  of the children of the world](http://www.foodaidfoundation.org/world-hunger-statistics.html).

EDIT...................................................................

Comments often disappear or go unpunished. I am now including [these]  as they seem to be relevant, especially in our pandemic times...

> One of the most heart-wrenching things I have witnessed in my life was near the end of the war when a delivery truck lost a case of eggs off the tailgate in the street, and the street-kids gathered round to scoop up the gooey mess and lick it off their fingers. It was probably the most nutritious thing they had to eat that week.

As John Lawler observed:

[>The unwashed masses don't have lefovers.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/550547/what-is-the-opposite-of-leftovers?noredirect=1#comment1355020_550547)

> https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/550547/what-is-the-opposite-of-leftovers?noredirect=1#comment1355020_550547

Comment: "Need insulates me from the embarrassment of choice."

Comment: I think your secondary term, **reject**, is perfect for what OP described.

Answer (score 7):

**salvage** describes both the OP and the comment scenario. You rescued the sugar from waste and extracted some residual utility if not your full value.  Same with the evening duration with girlfriend or brother: you rescued it from waste, and extracted some residual utility if not your full value.

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/salvage):

> **salvage**:
>
> - the act of saving something (such as a building, a ship, or cargo) that is in danger of being completely destroyed
> - something (such as cargo) that is saved from a wreck, fire, etc.
> - something extracted (as from rubbish) as valuable or useful

Comment: I wrote an answer but I like yours better.

Comment: No phrase, no idiom, no expression. Just a word. I don't like this at all!

Comment: Yeah, but not sugar on the ground or wheat on the factory floor.

Answer (score 6):

The only idiom that I can think of is [One man's trash is another man's treasure](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/One+man's+trash+is+another+man's+treasure) which means:

> Prov. Something that one person considers worthless may be considered
>   valuable by someone else.

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs]

Comment: Usually that idiom goes the other way though, doesn't it? The first person throws something away, and someone who sees the value of it picks it out of the trash.

Answer (score 4):

*The man **offloaded** the dirty sugar by donating it to the poor.*

> **to offload** — (transitive) to get rid of things, work, or problems by passing them on to someone or something else.
>   *He offloaded the defective car onto an unsuspecting buyer.* – Meaning #2 from
>   https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/offload

Answer (score 3):

There's a neologism, not in any dictionary, that's gaining traction and that is "freecycle".

Rather than dispose of something unwanted, you freecycle it and someone who wants it takes it off your hands.

It has, in large, been driven by the [freecycle website](https://www.freecycle.org).

<sub>I have no affiliation with said website.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is widely used but I think it would be widely understood if you identified this act ***discarding to charity*** or ***charitable discard***

In the ["British Dictionary definitions"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discard) section for **discard** it reads:

> 1. (transitive) to get rid of as useless or undesirable

---

If you add the element of deception to the mix then you can say ***pawn-off to charity***

**pawn-off**

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pawn+off

> To get rid of or dispose of something deceptively by misrepresenting its true value.

Answer (score 1):

A ***white elephant*** gift might be a somewhat useful term in this situation.

From the British Dictionary entries on [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/white-elephant):

2. a possession that is unwanted by its owner

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any perfect match for what you've requested. But on second thought, here's an *un*related non-answer.

**On second thought** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+second+thought)

> after having thought about something again.
>
> *"On second thought we decided that it would be too expensive to fly, so we took a bus instead."*

Comment: **Un-related**: Not related. See **related**.

Comment: @Constant'sErik What do you mean?

Comment: **Un-related**: Not related. See **related**. *(pun intended)* I mean, it's not as related as you say. "On second thought" is an expression that means "My second thought is that". It doesn't mean "I've decided to donate [(ant)onym], instead of trashing it."

Comment: @Constant'sErik Haha, sorry I was a tube late. :)