# What is the opposite of leftovers?

Tags: phrase-requests, antonyms

Like some  family cooks, I often prepare more than is necessary to feed a hungry family; however, I hate throwing away food, and always try to re-serve creatively the following day.

Today, I was talking to my wife about how sometimes leftovers  are better than ________, as they soak in the sauces and absorb more flavor.

I described them to her as "first-serve", but that sounds like a Tennis term.

I looked up [antonyms for "leftovers"](https://www.synonyms.com/antonyms/LEFTOVERS), and got nothing.

Is there a word or phrase to describe ***the meal served before the leftovers***?

Comment: "fresh-cooked food", perhaps?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresh_food If it is as obvious as that I will delete the Q...but that does not answer why I cannot find an antonym online.

Comment: Probly something like _the original_ (or _the originals_ if it's count instead of mass food).

Comment: @JohnLawler But is that how the unwashed masses would describe it?

Comment: Unwashed masses don't have leftovers.

Comment: @JohnLawler I am humbled...hunger is certainly *the most important* issue on the planet.

Comment: Relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334706/to-donate-something-you-want-to-throw-away/334761#334761

Comment: Fresh or new-made food would work.

Comment: https://www.synonym.com/synonyms/fresh-food This link has others too.

Comment: @Cascabel (*!*!! Tablets with touch screens) I think it is as simple as "fresh (cooked) food" but the thing to remember is that fresh cooked food is the base condition and leftovers are something else which needs a specific name. Because the fresh cooked is the norm it does not need a specific term to describe it.

Comment: Untouched (food):  not handled, used, or tasted.  (Annabel pushed aside her untouched plate.) ?  (Source Google)

Comment: I would say "rightunders".

Comment: I've said "this is better as leftovers than it was the first time around".

Comment: Virgin portions. "Sometimes leftovers are better than virgin portions".